# Embedding a form in a partial with a foreach statement

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Objective: 
list a set of records with a checkbox next to each along with a "delete" input.  If the user checks one checkbox or multiple checkboxes, the submit action will get the id of each checkbox and delete corresponding record(s).

I know this functionality is provided on the backend, but I'm trying provide the functionality to the frontend users that are logged in.

Update: I can now render the widget correctly, but am still having difficulty capturing the ID of the checkbox(s) that are selected.  Help here would be appreciated.

Index page:

```
<h1>Jobs</h1>
<?php include_partial('list', array('saved_jobss' => $saved_jobss, 'form' => $form)) ?>
//I'm not sure if I can even pass two objects??
```

Index action:

```
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
     $userId = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getId();
     $this->saved_jobss = Doctrine_Core::getTable('saved_jobs')->getSavedJobs($userId);    
     $this->form = new Saved_JobsForm();
  }
```

Partial page named: _list

```
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th>Company:</th>
      <th>Job name:</th>
      <th>Job No.</th>
      <th>Saved:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <?php foreach ($saved_jobss as $saved_jobs): ?>      
    <tr>
      <td> 
          <?php echo $form['id']->renderRow() ?>
      <td>
           <a href="
               <?php 
                   $jobId = $saved_jobs->getJobId();                
                   echo 'job/'.$saved_jobs->getJob($jobId);
               ?>
           ">
               <?php 
                   $jobId = $saved_jobs->getJobId();
                   echo $saved_jobs->getJobCompany($jobId);
               ?>
           </a>
      </td>
      <td>
               <?php 
                   $jobId = $saved_jobs->getJobId();
                   echo $saved_jobs->getJobName($jobId);
               ?>
      </td>
      <td>
               <?php 
                   echo $saved_jobs->getJobId();
               ?>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo date("M-j-y", strtotime($saved_jobs->getCreatedAt())) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Action:

```
  public function executeSubmit(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
      $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post'));
      $params = $request->getPostParameters();                   
      $this->redirect('saved_jobs/deleteConfirmation?'.http_build_query($params));       
  }
```

Form class:

```
class Saved_JobsForm extends BaseSaved_JobsForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
      $this->widgetSchema['id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox();          
      $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('id', false); 
  }
}
```

I tinkered with the idea of using javascript, but was unsure if that was the way to go or not.  Any help, or a point in the right direction would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly you can pass as many objects to a partial as required ..

Comment: okay, got the widget working correctly, now I'm just having difficulty capturing the id of the checked records in the list to pass to my parameter string.

Comment: why are you using this Saved_JobsForm ? You should just list your jobs and create a delete action. If you're worried about CSRF, you have a nice method ($request->checkCSRFProtection()) to check it agains BaseForm that is just enough for it.

Comment: Well, I'd still have the same difficulty I'm experiencing now, in capturing the listed record ID by the checkbox value, if I were to do it the way you suggested (which is probably the correct way to go about it).  However, instead starting from scratch, it would be beneficial to learn how to capture the record id from a selected checkbox.

Comment: You must not render a widget several times!

Comment: So what's the solution here?  I see it done all the time... a list of records with a checkbox next to them that you select so you can delete them or take other action on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I just passed a link to each record with the action and record Id.